# Why is the box flashing colors in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

so after the black box shrinks and then expands, I want to have these 2 colorful boxes expand out of the black background (sounds a bit confusing but you'll see what I mean). Is there a reason that these colorful boxes I'm trying to make are flashing instead of staying?

```
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d, %d" %(250, 10)
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
SIZE = (650, 650)   
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)



RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)


x = 650
y = 650
count = 0
secx = 1
secy = 1
firstsx = 325
firstsy = 325


run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    if x >= 1:
        x -= 1
        y -= 1
        count += 1

        randcolor = (random.randint(0,255)), (random.randint(0,255)),(random.randint(0,255))

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, randcolor, (1,1, x, y))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0,0, x, y))

        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(3)

    if count > 649:
        count += 1
        secx = count-650
        secy = count-650

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0,0, secx, secy))
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(3) 

    if count > 1399:
        count += 1
        firstsx -= 1
        firstsy -= 1

        randcolor = (random.randint(0,255)), (random.randint(0,255)),(random.randint(0,255))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, randcolor, (325,0, firstsx, firstsy))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, randcolor, (0,325, firstsx, firstsy))
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(3)
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes thank you for reminding me I check-marked your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually do is to update the display and wait after drawing the 1st box. At this point the 2nd box is not drawn at all.
Just do 1 `pygame.display.flip()` and `pygame.time.wait(3)` at the end of the application loop.

Furthermore you have to define the random colors before the main application loop. The rapidly changing colors makes the box flashing:

```py
randcolor = (random.randint(0,255)), (random.randint(0,255)),(random.randint(0,255))
randcolor1 = (random.randint(0,255)), (random.randint(0,255)),(random.randint(0,255))
randcolor2 = (random.randint(0,255)), (random.randint(0,255)),(random.randint(0,255))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    if x >= 1:
        x -= 1
        y -= 1
        count += 1
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, randcolor, (1,1, x, y))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0,0, x, y))

    if count > 649:
        count += 1
        secx = count-650
        secy = count-650
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0,0, secx, secy)) 

    if count > 1399:
        count += 1
        firstsx -= 1
        firstsy -= 1
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, randcolor1, (325,0, firstsx, firstsy))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, randcolor2, (0,325, firstsx, firstsy))

        if firstsx == 0:
            x, y = 650, 650
            count = 0
            firstsx, firstsy = 325, 325

    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(3)
```

Comment: I tried this code and it is still flashing. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: @conyieie Yes, define the colors before the loop. I've changed the answer.